# Sending parameters with xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, xml, parameters, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to send paramaters with xmlhttprequest but I dont know how. I have an html code with a form and where I create the xmlhttprequest objet and a php code where I want to send the parameters of my form and show them. So, the thing is that it show me the **Notice: Undefined variable** error, as the variables are not correctly sent. Both codes are in my xampp/htdocs folder.

These are the codes:

HTML & JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
</head>
<body>

    
    <form name="ajax" method="post">
        
        
        
        Surname: <input id="surname" type="text" required/>
        <br>    
        <br>                  
        Name: <input id="name" type="text" required />
        <br>      
        <br>        
        Phone: <input id="phone" type="tel" required/>
        <br>         
        <br>     
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">

    </form>

      <script>
            
            var surname=document.getElementById("surname");
            var name=document.getElementById("name");
            var phone=document.getElementById("phone");

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){

            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status==200){
                document.write(this.response);
            }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/htdocs/show.php surname="+surname+"&name="+name+"&phone="+phone,false);
            xhttp.send();
            
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP called "show.php":

```
<?php


$surname;
$name;
$phone;


echo $surname."<br>".$name."<br>".$phone;


?>
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: `var surname=document.getElementById("surname").value;` (same for the others) and `xhttp.open("GET","show.php?surname="+surname+"&name="+name+"&phone="+phone);`

Comment: Here's a 2022 version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Luwagy9m/ (note that your PHP code needs to say `$surname = $_POST['surname'];` (same for the others) and you can use `echo "$surname<br>$name<br>$phone";` instead.

Comment: The space here: `.../htdocs/show.php surname...=` should be replaced with a question mark: `.../htdocs/show.php?surname=...`. At which point you'll be getting the sent vars in `$_GET`: (e.g: `$surname = $_GET['surname']`)

Comment: `show.php` file also has something wrong. You should retrieve your data from `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables.

Comment: I see my code problems, thank you all Chris G, tao, Fasoeu .